# LeetCode 124. Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum

Tags: java, tree, binary

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [124. Binary Tree Maximum Path Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-maximum-path-sum/description/):

> A **path** in a binary tree is a sequence of nodes where each pair of adjacent nodes in the sequence has an edge connecting them. A node can only appear in the sequence **at most once**. Note that the path does not need to pass through the root.
>
> The **path sum** of a path is the sum of the node's values in the path.
>
> Given the `root` of a binary tree, *return the maximum **path sum** of any **non-empty** path.*
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> **Input:** `root = [1,2,3]`
> **Output:** `6`
> **Explanation:** The optimal path is `2 -> 1 -> 3` with a path sum of `2 + 1 + 3 = 6`.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - The number of nodes in the tree is in the range `[1, 3 * 10`<sup>`4`</sup>`]`.
> - `-1000 <= Node.val <= 1000`

This is my code:

```
class Solution {
    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode root) {
        int[] max= new int[1];
        int res = dia(root, max);
        return max[0];       
    }
 
   public static int dia(TreeNode root,int[] max){
        if(root==null){
            return 0;
        }
        int lh = Math.max(0,dia(root.left, max));
        int rh =  Math.max(0,dia(root.right, max));
        max[0] = Math.max(max[0], lh+rh+root.val);
        return root.val +  Math.max(lh,rh);
    } 
}
```

For the input `[-3]` (which is a tree with just one node, having the value -3), my code returns 0, but the expected answer is -3.

How to account for this particular test case?

I am simply taking the max of 0 and the recursive calls to discount negative node values.

Since it doesn't make sense to add a negative value, I decided to take max of 0 and the recursive calls `root.left`, similarly for 0 and `root.right`.

But now I don't know how to go about a single node with negative value.

How should I adapt my code to cover such cases?

Answer (score 0):

> Since it doesn't make sense to add a negative value, I decided to take max of 0 and the recursive calls `root.left`...

The idea to take the max of 0 and the returned value is fine.

> now I don't know how to go about a single node with negative value

The problem is not with taking the max of 0 and the returned values from recursion, but with the next statement where you take the max of `max[0]` and the path sum that includes `root.val`. For the failing case, that means that the negative value of the single node can never win from the 0 that you have initialised `max[0]` with at the start of your algorithm. But realise that this initialisation value of 0 does not correspond to any realistic path.

The correction is straightforward: don't initialise `max[0]` with 0, but either with an extreme negative value:

```
        int[] max = {Integer.MIN_VALUE};
```

or with a *realistic* value, which could be `root.val` (representing a path with only that node):

```
        int[] max = {root.val};
```

Both will make the code produce the correct value also when a negative value is expected.

Note that the second solution uses the given information that the given tree will not be empty.